Solving a trigonometric equation from a geometry problem
Question statement: In triangle $ABC$, angle $A = 54^\circ$ and angle $C = 24^\circ$. $P$ is a point on $AC$ such that $AP = BC$. Find angle $CBP$. (HK IMO Prelim 2015)
I am looking into using trigonometry to solve this problem. Although the equation is obtained, I do not know how to solve it by hand
$$\tan (24^\circ+x) = \frac{\sin(24^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)}{\sin(54^\circ)-\cos(54^\circ)\sin(24^\circ)}$$
On calculator it checks out that $x = 6^\circ$. However, how to solve this by hand? Are there any general methods to solve such trigonometric equations without using a calculator?

Put $x = 18$ degrees. Then $\cos(3x) = \sin(2x)$ and $4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x) = 2 \sin x \cos(x)$. Thus $4\cos^2(x) - 3 = 2\sin(x)$ and $4(1-t^2) - 3 = 2t$ where $t = \sin x$. Hence we can find $t = \sin x$ and get $t = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}4$. After it we can find $\sin(54) = \sin (3x) = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}4$. Hence we also know $\cos(54)$. Further, $\sin (24) = \sin(54 - 30) = \sin(54) \cos(30) - \cos(54) \sin(30)$.
Hence we may find the value from R.H.S. of your equation. It will be equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Now it's sufficient to note that $\tan (24 + x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ if $x = 6$ degrees, q.e.d.
